# Wordpress admin-ajax.php CPU high usage

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I've built a WordPress [website](http://jetronics.ae) and I am having issue from my hosting provider that admin ajax is consuming too much CPU usage at server. I got the notice that my site will get suspended and I am looking forward to fix it.

Following are the solutions I've tried so far.

1. I installed HeartBeat plugin and did set interval for 60 seconds.
2. Added code to minimize requests:

   ```
   <?php 
   add_action( 'init', 'my_deregister_heartbeat', 1 );
   function my_deregister_heartbeat() {
   global $pagenow;

   if ( 'post.php' != $pagenow && 'post-new.php' != $pagenow )
       wp_deregister_script('heartbeat');
   } 
   ?>
   ```
3. I removed all the plugins but still getting same CPU usage.

I will really appreciate if someone can help me to fix this issue.

Comment: @KirkBeard I tried to remove all the plugins and waited for 2 hours but it didn't dropped the CPU usage. All I want is to stop spikes for Ajax as site is live in production and its giving customer sales per day. If I get it down then it will be problem for him. I tried all the solutions before posting but none worked.

Comment: Its already a business package. If I need to upgrade it from this point then I guess I will go with VPS with Nginx. Nginx helps to restrict such issues.